# Error pushing application to heroku - class/object is already defined

Tags: git, scala, heroku, lift

I have a Lift application that I'm pushing to Heroku. I have followed the following tutorial to setup my project. - http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/10/3/scala/

When I do the `git push heroku master` command and all the dependencies have been downloaded, I get the following error:

```
info] Done updating.
       [info] Compiling 34 Scala sources to /tmp/build_3mu8dl4lcbqoj/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
       [error] /tmp/build_3mu8dl4lcbqoj/src/main/scala/code/models/Model.scala:97: CardAttribute is already defined as class CardAttribute
       [error] class CardAttribute extends MongoRecord[CardAttribute]
       [error]       ^
```

The project compiles fine locally so I'm not sure why its saying classes/objects already exist. Is this to do with the way heroku uploads projects? Maybe the projects cache is causing the issue?

Comment: So if you run `sbt clean stage` it works locally?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but maybe this can help somebody else.

I had the same problem, I was refactoring my code and I changed a package name then I tried to push to Heroku and it was failing due to duplicate objects. My mistake was that I was using `git add .` that ignores deleted files on my git version:

> warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
>   whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
>
> **Paths like 'app/.DS_Store' that are
>   removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.**
>
> - 'git add --ignore-removal ', which is the current default,
>     ignores paths you removed from your working tree.
> - 'git add --all ' will let you also record the removals.
>
> Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.

The solution was to set Heroku to clean with  `heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true` and then on the git side `git add . -A && git commit -m "message" && git push heroku master`.